# How to ensure the creation of the main menu without clicking on its items?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I need to access the widgets from the MMenu instance, from my application's main menu, but I found that the menu items are only created when displayed for the first time, when clicking on the menu item.

Is there a way to force the creation of all main menu widgets without having to click on all the items on the first level of the menu?

Note: I need to access the items because my application copies some items from the main menu to my main toolbar.

I tried creating the items by calling `MenuManagerRenderer.createWidget( mMenu, mainMenuParent )`. But the result was not what was desired. Items were duplicated, items that shouldn't be visible became visible, etc.

Ideally, the creation of items should be done in the same way as when we first clicked on the menu item.

Comment: No I don't think you can do that. Why do you need to copy from the MMenu items? Surely the menu and tool bar should just be referencing the same command id.

Comment: Hello, @greg-449. Thank you for your answer.

We copied the main menu items to the toolbar because we simulated the main menu with items in the toolbar as we needed some features for the main menu items which did not exist in Eclipse 3.x. This is optional in our application. 

We are migrating to Eclipse 4 and we wanted to maintain this behavior, but it looks like we will have to think of another strategy.

Comment: I still don't see why you need to copy anything. Are you just defining things in the Application.e4xmi (or fragment)? In which case you just put the equivalent tool bar items also in the e4xmi

Comment: Yes, apparently we will have to do just that.